# jQuery full calendar addEventSource not woking

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, datasource

**HTML :**

```
<div id='calendar1' class='right-panel-item'> </div>
```

**Intializing code (Works perfect):**

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
        events: "calendarAdmin?assignToUserId="+idValue,
                 ..... (Goes like this )
```

**On change of something :**

```
            var events = {
                      url: "calendarAdmin?assignToUserId="+ui.item.id,
                      type : 'GET'
                };
            $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('removeEventSource');
            $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
            $('#calendar1').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

This is not updating the events.
When I traced this is fire bug

```
var calendar = $.data(this, 'fullCalendar');
```

The value of calendar was `undefined`. So it exits the loop without applying the result.

Answer (score 0):

Look into fetching data independently of fullcalendar, on my machine I was never able to get any php scripts working (even the demos provided by the creator). Good luck!